# What is the most common method of passing params into modules?

Tags: node.js, express, module

So I am after the most common or recommended way to pass arguments, modules or parameters into other modules e.g.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth2;

var app = express();
var config = require('./config.js')(app, crypto, mongoose, OAuth);
var models = require('./models')(mongoose); /*etc.*/
```

Or would it be considered more common to extend `app` e.g.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.crypto = require('crypto');
app.mongoose = require('mongoose');
app.OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth2;

var config = require('./config.js')(app);
var models = require('./models')(app); /*etc.*/
```

Or it would be safer to extend an other object and pass that e.g.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var modules = {};

modules.crypto = require('crypto');
modules.mongoose = require('mongoose');
modules.OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth2;

var config = require('./config.js')(app, modules);
var models = require('./models')(app, modules); /*etc.*/
```

Or, are all of these edge-cases and should I take an other approach?

I don't want to construct new OAuth2 instance each time I need to use OAuth in my app, so I am currently creating a single OAuth2 instance in my config and then passing config into my routes; could I still do this and require `config.js` in each module (e.g. `routes.js`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you do not treat crypto, mongoose and Oauth2 as parameters.

your code should like this:

// app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config.js')(app);
var models = require('./models')(app);
```

// config.js or models.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth2;

module.exports = function (app) {
   // your code
}
```

all require('mongoose') will share the same instance. If you call mongoose.connect() on app.js then config.js and models.js get connected too.

---

There are some package on the world that may send required module as parameter, that because they got trouble with version conflict. But that only happend if config.js and models.js are separated module (modules which has it own package.json)

---

About your 3 examples:

- the first is ok
- the second is bad, it should be require('./config.js)(options); // options = {...}
- the third is ok

Comment: Thanks, I have changed `global` to `modules` in the example; it was not my intention to use the global object in Node.js. Is the last example still bad practice?

Comment: updated :), it's ok, i think we should minimize dependencies and relation between module as much as possible